# Help with this solution of quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

In one of the solved examples in the book I'm following, the following expression arises after considering $D > 0$ for a certain equation:

$$D = (n+1)^2p^2  - 2pq(n^2+1) + (n-1)^2q^2$$

From this, the following step was derived:

$$\{(n+1)^2p-(n-1)^2q\}(p-q) > 0$$

or

$q$ cannot lie between $p$ and $\left( \dfrac{n+1}{n-1} \right)^2p$.

First of all, I'm not sure how the step was arrived, and finally, how the range of $q$ was determined. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand out $\{(n+1)^2p-(n-1)^2q\}(p-q)$, you end up with the first expression.

In particular, $ \{(n+1)^2p-(n-1)^2q \}(p-q)=(n+1)p^2-(n+1)^2pq+(n-1)^2q^2-(n-1)^2pq $. Combining the $pq$ terms, we observe that $-(n+1)^2pq-(n-1)^2pq=-2pq(n^2+1)$.

Then the inequality comes from the fact that $D>0$.

To see this range condition, we first write the inequality as $(n+1)^2p(p-q)>q(p-q)(n-1)^2$. Then if $q<p$ we can cancel the $p-q$ and divide by $(n-1)^2$ to get $q<\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n-1)^2}p$. Conversely, if $q>p$, then dividing by $p-q$ switches the inequality so that $q>\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n-1)^2}p$. Thus, $q$ cannot be between the numbers $p$ and $\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n-1)^2}p$.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a lot time to understand the answer, but finally I get it. :)

Comment: No problem! Sorry if my response was unclear.